# Bind to property in App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a quick question: I want to bind a Solidcolorbrush, which is located in App.xaml's Resources. It has a key assigned to it, but how would I bind to that property from another page?

Here is the App.xaml itself:

```
<Application x:Class="Mplayer.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="PrimaryAccentColor" A="255" R="3" G="169" B="244"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryAccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource PrimaryAccentColor}"/>
        <Color x:Key="SecondaryAccentColor" A="255" R="3" G="169" B="244"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SecondaryAccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource SecondaryAccentColor}"/>
        <Color x:Key="LightBackgroundColor" A="255" R="3" G="169" B="244"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource LightBackgroundColor}"/>
        <Color x:Key="DarkBackgroundColor" A="255" R="3" G="169" B="244"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DarkBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource DarkBackgroundColor}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

If I then have a page which I want to bind to the `PrimaryAccentColorBrush`, how would that bind look?

I tried setting the bind to `{Binding Path={StaticResource PrimaryAccentColorBrush}}`, but it did not locate it.

Any help would be appreciated =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it... try this instead:

```
<TextBlock Background="{Binding Source={StaticResource PrimaryAccentColorBrush}}" />
```

Although you don't seem to have a `PrimaryAccentColorBrush` in your example... did you mean `PrimaryAccentBrush`?

Comment: Haha yes. I meant PrimaryAccentBrush. But thank you very much for the help.

Comment: You don't need the `Binding` if you're referencing a resource.

Comment: I know that, but the question author asked how to bind to the resource, so I just showed them what they asked for.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use `Binding`, just use `StaticResource`, like you already do:

```
Property="{StaticResource PrimaryAccentBrush}"
```

Comment: @Tokfrans: Need more help?